# Django Form Not Sending File via Modal

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to upload a file via a form inside a bootstrap modal.

`request.POST` correctly shows the file name in QueryDict, but `request.FILES` shows an empty MultiValueDict.

For comparison, I also tried another version of the form that is exposed in the page, which seems to be working perfectly.

What's the difference? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- EXPOSED FORM -->
    <form action="." method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ file_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    
    <!-- MODAL VERSION -->
    <a href="#" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#statusModal">
        Modal
    </a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="statusModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">UPLOAD FILE</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <form action =".?&status=status-update"　enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "post">
              <div class="modal-body">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ file_form.as_p }}
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">            
                  <input class="btn green-button" type = "submit" value = "Send">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from upload_file.forms import FileForm
from upload_file.models import File

def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        print(request.POST)
        print(request.FILES)

        file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if file_form.is_valid:
            file_form.save()
            
            return redirect('/upload_file/')

    file_form = FileForm()

    return render(request, 'upload_file/index.html', {
        'file_form': file_form,
    })
```

**EDIT:**

Adding here the rendered HTML:

```
<body>

    <!-- UPLOAD FILE -->
    <form action="." method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="VOmIk8wKOSzjPQoxy2fh8mWlDIF2TK3ILEOXXSJcyfKxvMLR4bsJQLnUI02XNe4U">
        <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="default" maxlength="10" required id="id_name"></p>
<p><label for="id_file">File:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="id_file"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    

    <!-- MODAL VERSION -->
    <a href="#" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#statusModal">
        Modal
    </a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="statusModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">UPLOAD FILE</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <form action =".?&status=status-update"　enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "post">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="VOmIk8wKOSzjPQoxy2fh8mWlDIF2TK3ILEOXXSJcyfKxvMLR4bsJQLnUI02XNe4U">
                <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="default" maxlength="10" required id="id_name"></p>
<p><label for="id_file">File:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="id_file"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">            
                  <input class="btn green-button" type = "submit" value = "Send">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to send the data?

Comment: Please share what `request.POST` and `request.FILES` is printed out.

Comment: @allexiusw Not using Ajax. Pretty new to this whole thing.

Comment: request.POST: `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['D6rV0GSLcjjLn5ZWfYyvAgd1vlMHZOqXtWTaDq5dWGuZ31mgL7LXiFEAAD9CTir9'], 'name': ['default'], 'file': ['Screen Shot 2021-08-05 at 6.24.30 PM.png']}>`
request.FILES: `<MultiValueDict: {}>`

Comment: What happen if you change: `if file_form.is_valid:` to `if file_form.is_valid():` do you have any difference?

Comment: When it is from the exposed form (non-modal), the request.FILES shows `<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Screen Shot 2021-08-05 at 6.24.30 PM.png (image/png)>]}>`

Comment: Changing `if file_form.is_valid:` to `if file_form.is_valid():` doesn't make any difference for this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236750/discussion-between-shun-and-allexiusw).

Comment: I can see that for some reason the `file` is in `request.POST` instead of `request.FILES`, so I would assume Bootstrap somehow changed/omitted the input's `type=file` parameter, so the value is send as a part of POST. Can you add into the question how the from is actually rendered instead of `{{ file_form.as_p }}`?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Please check. Thanks

Comment: So the modal disappear after you submit the form in there, or the whole page is redirected? If only the modal is closed, then I assume Bootstrap is hijacking the form submit (otherwise the whole page would redirect), and the way how it submits the form is via ajax. Which does not upload the file, it just sends JSON. Do you have any javascript on the page for handling the form?

Comment: It is redirected to the original page itself after the form submission. I have no javascript written for the form. Is that necessary?